# HOW TO SELECT PREVIOUS ROW VALUE?

Tags: sql, ms-access

How to get a value from previous result row of a SELECT statement

If we have a table called cardevent and has rows [ID(int) , Value(Money) ] and we have some rows in it, for example

```
ID --Value

1------70 
1------90
2------100
2------150
2------300 
3------150 
3------200 
3-----250 
3-----280
```

so on...

How to make one Query that get each row ID,Value and the previous Row Value in which data appear as follow

```
ID --- Value ---Prev_Value

1 ----- 70 ----------  0 
1 ----- 90 ---------- 70
2 ----- 100 --------  90 
2 ------150 -------- 100
2 ------300 -------- 150
3 ----- 150 -------- 300 
3 ----- 200 -------- 150 
3 ---- 250 -------- 200 
3 ---- 280 -------- 250
```

so on.

i make the following query but it's so bad in performance in huge amount of data

```
SELECT cardevent.ID, cardevent.Value, 
      (SELECT F1.Value
       FROM cardevent as F1 
       where F1.ID = (SELECT  Max(F2.ID)
                      FROM cardevent as F2 
                      WHERE F2.ID < cardevent.ID)
      ) AS Prev_Value
FROM cardevent
```

So can anyone help me to get the best solution for such a problem ?

Comment: why have you tagged with 2 different RDBMSs?

Comment: Duplicate to this one (other user, other table name): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742226/how-to-get-a-value-from-previous-result-row-of-a-select-statement

Comment: must be a homework question....

Comment: And:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062406

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one should work fine for both databases:

```
SELECT cardevent.ID, cardevent.Value, 
  (SELECT TOP 1 F1.Value
   FROM cardevent as F1
   WHERE F1.ID < cardevent.ID
   ORDER BY F1.ID DESC
   ) AS Prev_Value
FROM cardevent
```

**Update:** Assuming that ID is not unique, but that the combination of ID and Value is unique (you must specify what imposes your ordering on the table, so one knows what is *the previous row*), you must use this query:

```
select cardevent.ID, cardevent.Value, 
    (select TOP 1 F1.Value from cardevent as F1
     where (F1.ID < cardevent.ID) or (F1.ID = cardevent.ID and F1.Value < cardevent.Value)
     order by F1.ID DESC, F1.Value DESC
    ) AS Prev_Value
from cardevent
```

Comment: @MicSim -  I used your query, but it Showing Error "At Most one record can be returned by the subquery" nothing display in prev_value field

Comment: Output Showing like this....
PERSONID CARDEVENTDATE Expr1002 Prev_Value
#Name? #Name? #Name? #Name?
#Name? #Name? #Name? #Name?
#Name? #Name? #Name? #Name?
#Name? #Name? #Name? #Name?

Comment: Just tested above query with Access 2000 (don't have 2003 here) and it's working. Maybe you have extended/modified the query?

Comment: Your query is working Fine, but Id is not different all the time for the value.  Example. 
id, value - 1 100, 2 200, 2 400, 2 500, 3 100 3 200 so on..   
So Result is.. 
1 100 0, 2 200 100, 2 400 200, 2 500 400, 3 100 500, 3 200 100 so on.

Comment: @MicSim - I used your updated query, but it Showing Error "At Most one record can be returned by the subquery"

Comment: I hope, you used the lower one! :-) (it's working for me) If it's not working for you, then you have some more columns in your query or still other data which makes problems.

Comment: Column using - select Id, name, titlename, value, min(time), max(time), (select TOP 1 F1.Value from cardevent as F1     where (F1.ID < cardevent.ID) or (F1.ID = cardevent.ID and F1.Value < cardevent.Value)     order by F1.ID DESC, F1.Value DESC    ) AS Prev_Value from table - But it showing   "At Most one record can be returned by the subquery" - How can i make a query for all the mentioned column? Please.

Comment: This is leading to nowhere... you can't use min(), max() functions in select without grouping by the other fields. You should really do a simple select and sort your data by ID and Value and then postprocess it in code.

Comment: Here a query for your updated column info, but the result makes absolutely no sense to me. Sorry I can't help you better, but as in programming: vague requirements, wrong results.

 select ID, name, titlename, value, min(time), max(time),
    (select TOP 1 F1.Value from cardevent as F1
     where (F1.ID < cardevent.ID) or (F1.ID = cardevent.ID and F1.Value < cardevent.Value)
     order by F1.ID DESC, F1.Value DESC
    ) AS Prev_Value
from cardevent
group by ID, value, name, titlename
order by ID, value, name, titlename

Comment: Leave the min(time), Max(time) - remaining how can i take.

Comment: This one works for me: SELECT ID, name, titlename, value,  (select TOP 1 F1.Value from cardevent as F1
     where (F1.ID < cardevent.ID) or (F1.ID = cardevent.ID and F1.Value < cardevent.Value)
     order by F1.ID DESC, F1.Value DESC
    ) AS Prev_Value
FROM cardevent

Comment: @MICSIM: Now Your query is working Fine. Thanks. One more thing
In my query am selecting a VALUE BETWEEN using where condition. like where VALUE between 90 to 250 from the above mentioned table, 
But it displaying 1, 90, 150 so on.. because 150 is wrong because am selecting a value from 90 to 250, so before no value it should print 0 or null. but it printing 150. How can i make a condition for this? almost we got only one thing we have to do. Please

Comment: If you want to have only some values, then just put the filter at the end of the query, after the last from. If it should apply to the before value, then also add it into the inner select where part as F1.Value.

Comment: @Micsim: am new to access 2003, not cleared from the above comments. can you please how can i make inner select for my query. please.

Comment: Please Can you edit your answer

Comment: wow it saved my day

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT C.ID, C.Value, COALESCE(C1.Value, 0)
FROM cardevent C
    LEFT JOIN cardevent C1
    ON C1.Id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM cardevent C2 where C2.Id < C.Id)
```

Comment: +1. This seems to be the fastes of all given solutions.

Comment: It seems to compile to the same execution plan as MicSim's solution - and it makes sense if you look closely. I'd say both are ok.

Comment: I didn't look close enough at the actual execution plans, only at the percentages given by SQL Server. All solutions are working afaik, main difference is execution time and readability. Yours is fastest (or as fast as MicSim's solution) and most readable. Mine is... well, not so good <g>

Comment: +1 for the use of COALESCE. Its not often I see this used but its a very useful command in SQL to know

Comment: Though COALESCE doesn't work in MS Access, just SQL Server.

Answer (score -1):

How does following perform?

```
SELECT F1.ID, F1.Value, F3.Value
FROM cardevent F1
     INNER JOIN (
        SELECT F1.ID, mID = MAX(F2.ID)
        FROM cardevent F1
             INNER JOIN cardevent F2 ON F2.ID < F1.ID
        GROUP BY F1.ID
      ) F2 ON F2.id = F1.ID
     INNER JOIN cardevent F3 ON F3.ID = F2.mID
UNION ALL
SELECT F1.ID, F1.Value, 0
FROM cardevent F1
     INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ID = MIN(ID) 
        FROM cardevent
      ) F2 ON F2.ID = F1.ID
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score -1):

I prefer `TOP 1` instead of `MAX(...)`, which IMHO should be also faster:

```
SELECT      C.ID, C.Value, COALESCE(C1.Value, 0)
FROM        cardevent C
LEFT JOIN   cardevent C1
        ON  C1.ID = (SELECT TOP 1 C2.ID FROM cardevent C2 WHERE C2.ID < C.ID ORDER BY C2.ID)
```

Comment: Using access 2003 database, is not accepting coalesce function

Comment: @Gopal: I am not about the efficiency of the code in MSAccess, but IIF and ISNULL should help: "IIF(ISNULL(C1.Value), 0, C1.Value))"