# How to insert a value from a different query into a report in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a report based on a crosstab query

day | incomings | payments | diff | balance

05  | 50 | 00

05  | 00 | 10

05  | 00 | 20

I have a summary for each day:

05 |     50        | 30      | 20    | ***_***

where *balance* is the value I want to take from a different query for the same day

Comment: Is it not possible for you to sum in, say, the group footer?

Comment: I did the sum in the day footer. but I need to take the balance value from a different query becouse it is like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067672/how-to-select-previous-row-value

Answer (score 1):

You can use domain aggregate functions in reports, set a control to something like:

```
=DlookUp("Balance","MyQuery","Day=#" & ADate & "#")
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208786

It might also be possible to create a query based on both the queries you need for the report.

Answer (score 0):

You could always have the main report with a certain record source.  Then add a sub report to it with a different record source.