# I am trying to get value from the row above the selected record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2016

Hi I am trying to get a value from row right above the result I got from the criteria in the query.
The code I am trying to use takes right to the first row instead to the one above the given result. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am new please help.

```
=DLookUp("TotalAmount","QryYearMonthAmount","IdCheck=" & DMax("IDCheck","qryYearMonthAmount"," IDCheck =[txtID] -1 "))
```

suppose if the row selected is 4 and the total amount is 3000 it should go the row just above 4 and select the total amount example 6000

[image].

Comment: Must concatenate [txtID], not embed between quote marks. Edit question to show sample data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HOW TO SELECT PREVIOUS ROW VALUE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067672/how-to-select-previous-row-value)