# Adding the current row + previous rows of one column and getting the summed value in corresponding row of another column in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is my query

[image: This is my query]

This is what I want to get

[image: This is what I want to get]

I want to get the summed value of current + previous rows of one column into same row of another column
To explain further
one column rows are :

```
4000
-650
-630
```

other columns rows should be like :

```
4000
3350  (i.e 4000-650)
2720   (i.e 4000-650-630)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HOW TO SELECT PREVIOUS ROW VALUE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067672/how-to-select-previous-row-value)

Comment: You didn't provide the formula to calculate Bag_In_Stock in the SQL.  It looks like what you want to do is a Totals query.  so google ms access totals query

Answer (score -1):

Ms Access has a DSum function locate it and use it to update each row with the total sum of the values on all previous records of a field.