# How to do SQL Server Reporting Services Matrix?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am using SQL Server 2008 and now I am stuck with a problem for past two days. I want to merge a particular group of cells in a SSRS Report.

I have used the below code in the Background Color property of the text box

=IIF((Previous(Fields!score.Value)=Fields!score.Value), "", Fields!score.Value)

I get a an error saying
"Error  [rsInvalidPreviousAggregateInTablixCell] The use of a Previous aggregate function in a TablixCell within Tablix ‘matrix1’ is not supported"

Can any one help me with the error.

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems pretty clear: Previous doesn't work in a matrix cell. You could get around this problem by finding the previous value in your SQL-Query.

[How to get a value from previous result row of a SELECT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742226/how-to-get-a-value-from-previous-result-row-of-a-select-statement)

Answer (score -1):

=IIF((Previous(Fields!score.Value)=Fields!score.Value), Nothing, Fields!score.Value)