# Get the following record in query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

If we have a table called Activity and has rows[ActivityCode and StartTime]
for example

```
ActivityCode-----StartTime<BR>
Lunch------------1200<BR>
MathClass--------1300<BR>
EnglishClass-----1500<BR>
EndOfSchool------1700<BR>
```

And now I want to make one SQL Query to display as follow:

```
ActivityCode-----StartTime-----EndTime<BR>
Lunch------------1200----------1300<BR>
MathClass--------1300----------1500<BR>
EnglishClass-----1500----------1700<BR>
EndOfSchool------1700----------1700<BR>
```

I am not sure how to do it. I tried to follow [How to get a value from previous result row of a SELECT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742226/how-to-get-a-value-from-previous-result-row-of-a-select-statement). But it didn't work as I expected. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a value from previous result row of a SELECT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742226/how-to-get-a-value-from-previous-result-row-of-a-select-statement)

Comment: Not really. I want to need the following value instead

Comment: Same concept would be used. Use `>` and ASC instead of `<` and DESC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query:

```sql
SELECT 
    Activity.ActivityCode, 
    Activity.StartTime, 
    Nz((Select Top 1 StartTime 
        From Activity As T 
        Where T.StartTime > Activity.StartTime 
        Order By StartTime Asc),
        [StartTime]) AS EndTime, 
    CDate(TimeSerial(Val([EndTime])\100,Val([EndTime]) Mod 100,0)-
        TimeSerial(Val([StartTime])\100,Val([StartTime]) Mod 100,0)) AS Duration
FROM 
    Activity;
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

I would use a subquery with aggregation:

```
select a.*,
       (select nz(min(a2.starttime), a.endtime)
        from activity as a2
        where a2.starttime > a.starttime
       ) as endtime
from activity as a;
```

Normally in such an example, there would be an additional column identifying a "grouping" of some sort -- such as a person.  If you have such a column, you would have an equality condition in the subquery as well as the inequality on time.

Also, there are much better ways to do this in almost any other database -- notably, the `lead()` function.

Comment: I am studying your code but I find this "nz(min(a2.starttime), a.endtime" is very confusing. Could you explain more?