# Subquery sorted by another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is a follow-up question to [Get the following record in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62808883/get-the-following-record-in-query).
But the task is a bit more complicated. I tried to modify the SQL query but I was not able to fulfill the task.

If we have two tables, one called Activity and has rows [ActivityCode and StartTime], and the another one called Students has rows [Name and ID]
for example:

```
Name-----ID-----ActivityCode-----StartTime<BR>
Tom------123------Lunch------------1200<BR>
Tom------123------MathClass--------1300<BR>
Tom------123------EnglishClass-----1500<BR>
Tom------123------EndOfSchool------1700<BR>
Mary-----369-----Lunch------------1200<BR>
Mary-----369-----ScienceClass-----1300<BR>
Mary-----369-----EnglishClass-----1600<BR>
Mary-----369-----EndOfSchool------1700<BR>
```

And now I want to make one SQL Query to display as follow:

```
Name-----ID------ActivityCode-----StartTime------EndTime<BR>
Tom------123---  Lunch------------1200-----------1300<BR>
Tom------123-----MathClass--------1300-----------1500<BR>
Tom------123-----EnglishClass-----1500-----------1700<BR>
Tom------123-----EndOfSchool------1700-----------1700<BR>
Mary-----369-----Lunch------------1200-----------1300<BR>
Mary-----369-----ScienceClass-----1300-----------1600<BR>
Mary-----369-----EnglishClass-----1600-----------1700<BR>
Mary-----369-----EndOfSchool------1700-----------1700<BR>
```

I follow the code, credits to Gustav:

```sql
SELECT 
    Activity.ActivityCode, 
    Activity.StartTime, 
    Nz((Select Top 1 StartTime 
        From Activity As T 
        Where T.StartTime > Activity.StartTime 
        Order By StartTime Asc),
        [StartTime]) AS EndTime, 
    CDate(TimeSerial(Val([EndTime])\100,Val([EndTime]) Mod 100,0)-
        TimeSerial(Val([StartTime])\100,Val([StartTime]) Mod 100,0)) AS Duration
FROM 
    Activity;
```

I tried to modify the part

```sql
Order By StartTime Asc
```

Because the whole query is sorted according to the Student ID which is from another table. But some message boxes popped up and I couldn't solve it. How can I modify it? thank you.

Comment: Should we assume Activity also has field for Student ID?

Comment: What field type is StartTime?

Comment: @user13851309 . . . Do you realize that I answered this version of your question on your previous question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62808883/get-the-following-record-in-query?

Comment: @June7 It is String

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry. I am new to SQL and it is not very friendly to me. I think both works to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this SQL:

```
SELECT Students.ID, [Name], ActivityCode, StartTime,
Nz((Select Top 1 StartTime FROM Activity As T 
        WHERE T.StartTime > Activity.StartTime AND T.ID=Activity.ID
        ORDER BY StartTime Asc),Startime) AS EndTime, 
DateDiff("h",TimeSerial(StartTime/100,0,0),TimeSerial(EndTime/100,0,0)) AS Duration
FROM Students INNER JOIN Activity ON Students.ID=Activity.ID;
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. But after input a bunch of data, a msgbox pops up and says the subquery can only return one value. Do you know why?

Comment: Just more data should not be an issue. I would have to review data to really know. However, just did minor edits on SQL in answer.

Comment: I think I have found the problem. Thank you anyway.